# Deploy application using Jenkinsfile and AWS Code deploy

Tags: jenkins, aws-code-deploy, jenkins-pipeline

I am migrating from Jenkins 1.x to Jenkins 2. I want to build and deploy application using Jenkinsfile. 
I am able to build gradle application, but I am confused about deploying application via AWS Codedeploy using Jenkinsfile.

Here is my jenkinsfile

```
node {
   // Mark the code checkout 'stage'....
   stage 'Checkout'
   // Get some code from a GitHub repository
      git branch: 'master', 
       credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx', 
       url: 'https://github.com/somerepo/someapplication.git'

   // Mark the code build 'stage'....
   stage 'Build'
   // Run the gradle build
      sh '/usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle build -x test -q buildZip -Pmule_env=aws-dev -Pmule_config=server'

    stage 'Deploy via Codedeploy'
    //Run using codedeploy agent
}
```

I have searched many tutorial but they're using AWS Code deploy plugin instead.
Could you help me deploying application via AWS Codedeploy using Jenkinsfile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively you can use AWS CLI commands to do code deployment. This involves two steps.

**Step 1** - Push the deployment bundle to S3 bucket. See the following command:

```
aws --profile {profile_name} deploy push --application-name {code_deploy_application_name} --s3-location s3://<s3_file_path>.zip
```

Where:

1. profile_name = name of AWS profile (if using multiple accounts)
2. code_deploy_application_name = name of AWS code deployment application.
3. s3_file_path = S3 file path for deployment bundle zip file.

**Step 2** - Initiate code deployment
The second command is the used to trigger code deployment. See the following command:

```
aws --profile {profile} deploy create-deployment  --application-name {code_deploy_application_name} --deployment-group-name {code_deploy_group_name} --s3-location bucket={s3_bucket_name},bundleType=zip,key={s3_bucket_zip_file_path}
```

Where:

1. profile = name of your AWS profile (if using multiple accounts)
2. code_deploy_application_name = same as step 1.
3. code_deploy_group_name = name of code deployment group. This is associated with your code deploy application.
4. s3_bucket_name = name of S3 bucket which will store your deployment artefacts. (Make sure that your role that performs code deploy has permissions to s3 bucket.)
5. s3_bucket_zip_file_path = same as step 1.